# Monomorphism from a sheaf to a flasque sheaf: determining the stalk.

Tags: ring-theory, differential-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $M$ be a topological Hausdorff space. We use the following definitions (as they may vary):

---

A **presheaf** $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of vector spaces $\mathcal{F}(U)$ for each open subset $U$ of $M$ equipped with restriction maps $R_{UV}:\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{F}(V)$ for any open subsets $U,V$ with $V\subset U$ for which the following holds:

- For any $U,V,W$ open subsets such that $W\subset V\subset U$, we have $R_{UW}=R_{VW}\circ R_{UV}$
- $R_{UU}=\text{Id}\vert_{\mathcal{F}(U)}$

An element of a presheaf is called a **section** of the presheaf.

A **sheaf** $\mathcal{F}$ is a presheaf such that the following holds for any open subset $U$ of $M$ and any open cover $\{U_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ of $U$:

- $f\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $f\vert_{U_{i}}:=R_{UU_{i}}(f)=0$ implies $f=0$ (note that $f\vert_{\cup_{i\in I}U_{i}}=f\vert_{U}=f$).
- If $\{f_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sections with $f_{i}\in\mathcal{F}(U_{i})$ for all $i\in I$ such that for all $i,j\in I$, $f_{i}\vert_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}}=f_{j}\vert_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}}$, then there exists $f\in\mathcal{F}(\cup_{i\in I}U_{i})=\mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $f\vert_{U_{i}}=R_{UU_{i}}(f)=f_{i}$ for all $i\in I$

A **morphism** $\psi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ between two sheaves is a collection of homomorphisms $\psi_{U}:\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$ compatible with restrictions: for any open subsets $U,V$ with $U\subset V$ denote by $R^{\mathcal{H}}_{UV}$ the restriction map associated with the sheaf $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{F}\text{ or }\mathcal{G}$; $\psi_{V}\circ R^{\mathcal{F}}_{UV}=R^{\mathcal{G}}_{UV}\circ\psi_{U}$

A **stalk** $\mathcal{F}_{x}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ in $x\in M$ can be seen as the set of equivalence classes for the following relation. Let $U$ and $U'$ be two open subsets containing $x$. We say that two functions $f\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ and $g\in\mathcal{F}(U')$ are equivalent if there exists an open subset $W\subset U\cap U'$ such that $R_{UW}(f)=R_{U'W}(g)$ (it is more properly defined with inductive limit). If $f\in\mathcal{F}(U)$, there canonically corresponds an equivalence class $f_{x}\in\mathcal{F}_{x}$ called the germ of $f$ in $x$.

---

There are two equivalent ways of defining an injective morphism between sheaves: either it has to be injective on each $\mathcal{F}(U)$ or it has to be injective on stalks.

My purpose is to prove that, for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of vector spaces, there exists a monomorphism from $\mathcal{F}$ to some flasque sheaf $\mathcal{G}$. A natural candidate for $\mathcal{G}$ is the collection of $\mathcal{G}(U):=\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}$ and a natural monomorphism is the following:

$$\psi_{U}:\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U):=\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}:f^{U}\mapsto (f^{U}_{x})_{x\in U}$$

where $f^{U}$ denotes a section of $\mathcal{F}$ over $U$ (i.e. an element of $\mathcal{F}(U)$) and $f^{U}_{x}$ denotes the germ of $f^{U}$ in $x$. I can do it when I use the definition saying that $\psi$ is injective if every $\psi_{U}$ is injective but I don't manage to do it whith the other definition since I'm unsure of the stalk $\mathcal{G}_{x}$.

This is why I needed to prove the equivalence between the two definitions. **Updated 03/02/16**: I was able to prove this equivalence. Still, I would like to know if it is possible to determine the stalk of the particular $\mathcal{G}$ (defined previously) in some $x$.

**EDIT**: It is probably better if I show what I think. Restriction maps for $V\subset U$ send $(f_{x})_{x\in U}\to(f_{x})_{x\in V}$. Let $U,U'$ be two open subsets containing some point $y$. Let $\varphi\in\mathcal{G}(U)$ and $\gamma\in\mathcal{G}(U')$. By definition of $\mathcal{G}$, $\varphi=(f_{x})_{x\in U}$ and $\gamma=(g_{x})_{x\in U'}$. They are equivalent if there exists an open subset $W\subset U\cap U'$ such that $(f_{x})_{x\in W}=(g_{x})_{x\in W}$, i.e. $f_{x}=g_{x},\,\forall x\in W$. It leads me to think that $\mathcal{G}_{y}=\mathcal{F}_{y}$ for any $y\in M$. But is that possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not very clear about what you are asking. Do you want to show the equivalent definitions of injective morphism or "actually, my problem is ......"? Its not very clear how equivalent definitions of injective morphism or "actually, my problem is ......" is related. Moreover, $\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U):=\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}:f^{U}\mapsto (f^{U}_{x})_{x\in U}$, the notations here are not clear. For example what is $f^U$? Probably it will help if you put more context and detail into it.

Comment: @Babai Thanks for your reply. I managed to prove the equivalence between the definition of monomorphisms of sheaves in terms of stalks and the one saying that a morphism of sheaves is injective iff any $\psi_{U}:\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$. I wanted to prove this equivalence because I did not succeed at determining the stalk of $\mathcal{G}$ (in my particular problem) in some $x$, so that I wasn't able to use the first definition (which I was supposed to). For the other part of your comment, I do not see what is not clear. $f^{U}$ is just an element of $\mathcal{F}(U)$.

Comment: Why is $\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$ is the map $\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}:f^{U}\mapsto (f^{U}_{x})_{x\in U}$?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what is not clear. 1. I wanted to prove the equivalence. 2. My particular problem, is to find, for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, a monomorphism (depending on $\mathcal{F}$) from $\mathcal{F}$ to a flasque sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ (flasque: restriction maps are surjective). A natural candidate for $\mathcal{G}$ is the collection of $\mathcal{G}(U)=\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}(U)$ and a natural candidate for the morphism is the one you have just written.

Comment: @MoebiusCrozer Why don't you edit the question with all this details properly? And your notations are still confusing for me, what is $\mathcal{F}_x(U)$?

Comment: @babai You are right, this notation does not mean anything, it is a mistake, but I did not use it in my original question. I shall edit the question with my computer (I am currently on a phone). Thanks for your time and your interesting remarks.